# Python - issue with plotting CandleStick plotly chart

Tags: python, plotly-python

I am having trouble plotting values on Candlestick plotly chart.
For some reason, I get all green bars instead of green/red bars. Green for when values are up and red when the values go down.

Here is my code that you can run as is if you just install cbpro:

```
# Import Dependencies
import time
import cbpro
import pandas as pd
import json
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from datetime import datetime

# Establish Public Client
public_client = cbpro.PublicClient()

# Create start and end time variable
stime = public_client.get_time()
etime = list(public_client.get_time().values())[0]
# Get past transaction for ETH
past_transactions = pd.DataFrame(public_client.get_product_historic_rates(product_id='ETH-USD'))
# Rename the columsn
past_transactions.columns= ["Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"]
# Format the date
past_transactions['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(past_transactions['Date'], unit='s')
# Set the date as index
past_transactions.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
# Sorting values by date
past_transactions.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=True, inplace=True)

# Plot the values on CandleStick plotly chart
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x= past_transactions.index,
                                            open = past_transactions['Open'],
                                            high = past_transactions['High'],
                                            low = past_transactions['Low'],
                                            close = past_transactions['Close']
                                            )])

fig.show()
past_transactions
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

This is going to sound a bit strange, but please hear me out. And I might be wrong here, but to me this seems to be a broblem with your dataset. Either the data is strange all the way, or the following references are wrong:

```
open = past_transactions['Open'],
high = past_transactions['High'],
low = past_transactions['Low'],
close = past_transactions['Close']
```

By that I mean that `lows` have been mixed up with `close` or something to that effect. And what on earth can I mean by `the data is strange all the way`? I look at candle charts from a variety of markets all day long, and what we're looking at in your figure just can not represent any "normal" market. In theory, there would be absolutely nothing wrong with a chart that looks like yours ***as lon as `close` is higher than `open` for each and every time interval***.

[image]

And that's *exactly* what we're looking at in your case with all those "flat" candles, meaning that `low = open` for all of them. Or in candle chart terms: we're not seeing *any* [`Lower Shadow`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikihow.com%2FRead-a-Candlestick-Chart&psig=AOvVaw3DdFLhHtkqWsUI84VuDuJX&ust=1641680801913000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCJids9_XoPUCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)

[image]

And that just would not happen for that many observations in any liquid and well functioning market. I *may* be wrong about that though, but I'm not wrong in that your plotly figure is producing the correct visualization given your data specifications.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am going to check the data and maybe there is an issue with time interval and how i am segmenting the data.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running the code you have added. But, I do get red and green bars. But the reds are not that visible because they are fewer in number and smaller. The plot:
[image: Plot with red and Green Bars]

Comment: Yeah, so I get the same plot. There should be way more red bars, almost as much as green bars. Which clearly is not right. This is how it should look like:
https://pro.coinbase.com/trade/ETH-USD

Comment: Oh! In that case, this does seem wrong. As I am new to this field, what do the colors represent in the link? Because, the candle plot in `plotly` uses colors based on "close value is higher (lower) then the open value are called increasing (decreasing)". The difference could be because of the difference in the definition of the color usage maybe?

Comment: So the green color should be there for any growing value. The peak of the value would be the green line extending up from the green line. That's the height of the value. The red bar should represent a declining value where the peak of the red value would be a red line extending from the red bar down.